# Is it possible to add user search filters to a ReferenceManyField in React Admin v3?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

With React Admin it is possible to add Filters to a List component. An example of this can be seen in the demo: https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/commands

[image: user search filters in List]

The code for this particular component: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/orders/OrderList.js

```
const OrderFilter = withStyles(filterStyles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
<Filter {...props}>
    <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />
    <ReferenceInput source="customer_id" reference="customers">
        <AutocompleteInput
            optionText={choice =>
                `${choice.first_name} ${choice.last_name}`
            }
        />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <DateInput source="date_gte" />
    <DateInput source="date_lte" />
    <TextInput source="total_gte" />
    <NullableBooleanInput source="returned" />
</Filter>));

...

const OrderList = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
<List
    {...props}
    filterDefaultValues={{ status: 'ordered' }}
    sort={{ field: 'date', order: 'DESC' }}
    perPage={25}
    filters={<OrderFilter />}
>
    <StyledTabbedDatagrid />
</List>
);
```

However, I can't figure out to add the same functionality to a **ReferenceManyField**. In the demo website this would for example be the Orders tab for a customer Edit component. Is there a way to configure a Filter component for the ReferenceManyField?

[image: Orders tab]

Answer (score 3):

probably you already found the right answer, but for those who still have this problem. Here is a simple solution. Just use List inside you ReferenceManyField.

```
const MyFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <ReferenceInput
            label="MyFilter"
            source="wallet"
            reference="wallets"
            sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }}
            filterToQuery={searchText => ({ name: searchText })}
            allowEmpty={true}
            alwaysOn
        >
            <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
);

<ReferenceManyField
    label={false}
    reference="wallets"
    target="user"
>
   <List filter={{ user: record.id}} filters={<MyFilter />}>
      <Datagrid {...props}>         
         <ReferenceField source="vendor" resource="vendors" reference="vendors">
            <TextField source="name"/>
         </ReferenceField>
      </Datagrid>
   </List>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer @Mattin. I did notice the moment the List component is injected, the ReferenceManyField target value is ignored. Your code has a { user: record.id } to share the filter, but record is always empty. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Thanks. It was the lack of `alwaysOn` that was causing it to not show for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListBase as the above answer, but when using ListBase, it ignores the target field in the ReferenceManyField.Therefore you need to give a filter to that.

```
    const DataFilter = (props) => (
         <Filter {...props}>
             <TextInput label="Search by DataCode" source="id" alwaysOn />
          </Filter>
     );

        <ReferenceManyField
          reference="reference"
          target="targetRef"
          filter={{ targetRef: props.id }}
        >
          <ListBase {...props}  >
            <ListToolbar
              filters={<DataFilter />}
            />
            <Datagrid>
             //datagrid fields
          </Datagrid>
          </ListBase>

        </ReferenceManyField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListBase` for this, [the change](https://marmelab.com/blog/2021/02/02/react-admin-february-2021-update.html#use-code-classlanguage-textltlistgtcode-everywhere-you-want) was added in 3.10+ versions.

```
<ReferenceManyField
    reference="some-reference"
    target="some-target">
    <ListBase syncWithLocation={true}>
        <ListToolbar
            filters={<YourFilter />}
            actions={<ListActions  hasCreate={true}/>}
        />
        <Datagrid>
            ///etc...
        </Datagrid>

        <Pagination/>
    </ListBase>
</ReferenceManyField>
```